# How do I stop agent presentations from appearing in GIS Map?

Tags: anylogic

I'm developing a model with a GIS map. I want the presentation of certain agents -- namely, custom library objects I am developing -- to appear *outside* the GIS map. When I move them outside of the map while I am developing the model, they are invisible; at runtime, they correctly appear where they should. I have explicitly excluded the agents from the GIS environment. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the agent and clicking on the graphical representation of it which is a picture in most cases. Then in the properties window check if "Icon" is checked like in the picture below.[image: Icon]

This will replace the default icon used by AnyLogic (the red circle with a human shape in it) with the selected presentation and as a result you can place the agent outside of the GIS map while developing.

Comment: That's unfortunately what I've resorted to doing, but it doesn't carry things like charts with it.

Comment: it should if you select the icon tick in the charts on the agent presentation, no?